# Don't update my code in container Node

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

Hi guys

In my project Node.js, I did some changes in the code server.js and save, after, rebuild my Dockerfile and up my docker-compose.yml, but I was execute my code in container NodeJS and it was not updated the code file in Container

How update the code file in Container ?

this is my project in GitHub:

https://github.com/wrj95/NodeDock

Comment: Try `docker build --no-cache` ?

Comment: I tryed this suggestion few minutes ago and didn't update the file this way

Comment: What commands are you using to run the container? Do you get any errors when you do so?

Comment: To run containers I used the command docker-compose up -d.      But I tried too a new Docker build, I tried - -no-cache and not updated the file in container.     I remove all container and images  after build again but this time update the files in container, but I believe that should have a command that update the file in container without to remove all but not found yet.   When I executed these commands no happened any errors to up the containers